# Google Calendar API - No constructor found

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I'm start to use Google Calendar API.
But when I try the Set Up in the link https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate I have a big problem.

I try to implement the constructor

```
Calendar service = new Calendar(httpTransport, accessProtectedResource, jsonFactory);
```

but this ins't in the library, this constructor not exists.

Can anybody help me to found a new solution for this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are referring to the Calendar service class defined in `com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar` and not the model class defined in `com.google.api.services.calendar.model.Calendar`.