# Java doesn't see Calendar API

Tags: java, netbeans, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-java-client

I imported Google calendar API on Netbeans with all the needed libraries but it looks like java can't see the API for an unknown reason, even thu I imported all the libraries...

Please help ...

G Calendar API can be found here : http:// developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it

image 1 : I cant create or manipulate a new event thru API

[image: image 1]

image 2 : all libraries imported

[image: image 2]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your snapshot it seems like the Calendar package is imported just fine. The problem seems to be that your `service` variable is undefined.

Comment: As you can see here it's the exact same code from G developers (check the Java tab on the bottom) : http://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list#try-it

Comment: That is a code snippet, it isn't complete, you might want to look at https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/instantiate for a way to get the service object (instance of Calendar)

Comment: Well that's a bit better as I know how create a service obj but i have now the same issue as this one 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10152775/google-calendar-api-no-constructor-found